# Cannot Sucessfully Delete Item From ListView In Set Counterpart

Tags: java, android

I feel like this shouldn't be a complicated problem, but I've tried reworking it and cannot think of a solution as to why it isn't working.

I have a listView that adds a ArrayList notes to it. For this listView, when you longpress on an item, it creates a pop up that deletes the item clicked. my set notesSet takes data from sharedPreferences and adds it to notes and gets updated when notes changes. This deletion is controlled by a Yes/No box. For some reason, I cannot remove the item from notes and have the listView show the updated form.

Here is the code for the long click:

```
myPref.edit().putStringSet("NN", notesSet).apply();

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(Schedule.this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Pop Up!")
                .setMessage("Ready to delete this task?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        SharedPreferences myPref = Schedule.this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.jackson.collegeplanner", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        Set<String> notesSet = new HashSet<String>(myPref.getStringSet("NN", null));
                        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(Schedule.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);
                        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        notesSet.remove(i);
                        notes.clear();
                        notes.addAll(notesSet);
                        myPref.edit().putStringSet("NN", notesSet).apply();
                        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                        /*
                        notes.remove(i);
                        notesSet.addAll(notes);
                        notes.clear();
                        */
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I've actually pinpointed the problem, I think, to these three lines of code. Problem is, I can't figure out what it is I'm doing

```
notesSet.remove(i);
notes.clear();
notes.addAll(notesSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a simple mistake, instead of passing String value to notesSet.remov(), you are passing integer value to it.

So make change like this

```
notesSet.remove(i)
```

to

```
notesSet.remove(notes(i))
```